# ifdown: interface eth0 not configured Error: ??? prefix is expectd rather than

Tags: networking

on Ubuntu 16.04, I tried to set static IP in order to communicate with a local device.
I changed /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.100.102
    netmask 255.2555.255.0
    gatway 192.168.100.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.100.1
```

After, I run the following command:

```
sudo ifdown eno1 && sudo ifup eno1
```

I got error:

```
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured Error: ??? prefix is expectd rather than ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error caused by two typos:
1. "2555" should be "255" 
2. "getway" should be "gateway"

After I fixed these two errors, my static IP address changed to 192.168.100.102